# Windows 7 the boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible

Tags: windows-7, boot, fde

I have a laptop that was running Symantec Endpoint Encryption on it. After upgrading from version 11.0 to 11.1.1 I'm able to authenticate at the  pre-boot screen but once Windows tried to load it fails with

[image]

I've create a WinPE Recovery disk and decrypted the drive but after booting I still get the same error. It's a MBR disk + BIOS legacy mode. I tried to use WinPe to boot and check bcdedit but I shows me the Windows Boot Loader is on drive D:\ which is the WinPE disc. Any ideas how can I verify it?

Answer (score 0):

If your encryption key is incorrectly applied, the content is not accessible by the boot system. You need to find a way to apply the correct decryption key to your drive, the one that was applied before the upgrade.

-Update-

Before attempting boot fix check in the BIOS to see if the HDD access mode did not switch between IDE/SATA/AHCI/RAID. Use the original setting and it should boot. If that did not changed, and if you are sure the drive is decrypted do the following:

- Boot to the Windows DVD, Select Next, Repair your computer
- Select Next, Command Prompt and to X:\sources\recovery, then type StartRep.exe to launch the automated startup repair utility. This must be repeated if it fails the first time.
- If it still fails, open the command prompt and type bcdedit. This will display the values for Windows Boot Manager. Look for Device. If it is set to unknown, type the following commands (assuming C: is your boot drive)

  bcdedit /set {DEFAULT.EN_US} device partition=c:

  bcdedit /set {DEFAULT.EN_US} osdevice partition=c:

  bcdedit /set {BOOTMGR.EN_US} device partition=c:

Reboot while removing the disk and system should boot fine.
If it does, you can re-encrypt your drive. Keep everything MBR+Legacy.

Comment: But the drive is already decrypted, if I run their recovery tool it says it's not encrypted, I also don't get the pre-boot any longer.

Comment: You can access content normally (if you connect it to an external SATA-USB adapter) ?

Comment: If you can access the BIOS, as Overmind suggested, check if your SATA settings are still the same. It should probably be AHCI. If that doesn't solve the problem, boot from the install medium (USB, DVD), go to Repair, then Advanced, then Command Line, and type "diskpart" (no quotes; press Enter), then "list disk" (same), "sel disk x" (where x is your hard drive; same) then "list volume", and see if your Windows partition is accounted for or not. If yes, you can repair your MBR after exiting diskpart. If not, you may have to reinstall, after resizing your current system partition if you want.

Answer (score 0):

My screen is the same as above except the error is Oxc000000e.
I fixed it by using Windows installation disk going into repair mode, command mode, then bootrec and did fixboot and fixMBR.  After that win7 Ultimate booted from hard disk